# Numerical operations on strings with C

Tags: c, string, addition

I have been asked to make a calculator taking the inputs as a string, so that we can we can calculate with long numbers the result should also be a string. I tried the addition part but it doesn't work with the two numbers being of different lengths. Could someone tell me where my code went wrong and how i can fix it ? Also an idea of how i would divide using this principle.

```
i = strlen(first);
j = strlen(second);
x = 0;

while(1)
{
   z = (first[i-1] - 48) + (second[j-1] - 48) + carry;
   carry = z/10;
   result1[x] = z%10 + 48;

   x++;
   i--;
   j--;

   if(i==0 && j==0)
   {   if(carry!=0)
       result1[x] = carry + 48;
       break;
   }
}

 i = strlen(result1);

for (i = 0, j = strlen(result1)-1; i < j; i++, j--)
   {
     c = result1[i];
     result1[i] = result1[j];
     result1[j] = c;
   }

puts(result1);
```

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "[tag:bignum]".

Comment: Don't say `- 48`. Say `- '0'`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start the summation with the least significant digits in each string; if the sum exceeds 9, you carry 1 over to the next more significant digit sum.  Just like you do on paper.  This also means you have to organize things so that you know how long each string (number) is, and deal with 'implicit zeroes' in front of the shorter number.

Comment: Ahh, implicit zeroes, thats brilliant. So would you recommend another loop that adds zeroes in the string so that they are of equal length ?

Comment: I'd suggest not adding to the string - you would have to create, copy, zero-pad the string (and then throw it away).  I've not done the measurements, but I'd be surprised if that was quicker than adding the zeroes by knowing that once you've reached the front (most significant digit) of one of the strings, you are at most going to be adding a carry to the remaining digits in the other string, and that only while there is a carry and the other digit is '9'.  Otherwise, you can simply copy the leading characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
z = (first[i-1] - 48) + (second[j-1] - 48) + carry;
```

This won't work if one of i or j is zero or negative. If you want to continue looping until both strings are consumed, then you could use ?: to avoid accessing the array unsafely. You may also find it easier to decrement i and j at the start of the loop.

```
if(i==0 && j==0)
```

This won't work if i != j. You need to find a better way to terminate the loop. (With careful conditional logic above you could even continue the loop until the carry is zero too.)